# How to limit QThread number

Tags: python, pyqt

Is it possible to limit number of threads started with `QtCore.QThread` via `Queue`. The code below starts as many running threads as there were submitted.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import Queue as queue

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
theQueue = queue.Queue()

class TheThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, theQueue, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.theQueue = theQueue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task = self.theQueue.get()
            self.sleep(1) 
            self.theQueue.task_done()

threads=[]
for i in range(1, 3): 
    thread = TheThread(theQueue)
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for i in range(len(threads)):
    theQueue.put(i)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's starting as many threads as you tell it to, via the `range(1,3)` call. You could send as many messages to those two threads as you wanted via the `Queue` object, and you'd never end up with more than two threads.

Comment: Now if I understand it correctly... Let's say there are 7 integers in  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] to be processed. I create two threads to do all the processing. Next using `for each in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]: theQueue.put(each)` I initiate 7 queue items. Method `.put()` aside from creating queue item allows to store a variable or value in it. Later this value-data can be retrieved by `run()` function using data=`theQueue.get()`. I thought the only way to send data to `run()` was to use `Thread` object. But `theQueue.put()`-`theQueue.get()` should be used to pass the arg data to function.

Comment: Yes, a `Queue.queue` is a data structure that allows you to pass arbitrary objects safely between threads. So you can have have the main thread feed as many items into the queue as you want, using `queue.put`. Then you can have as many child threads as you want pulling those items out of the queue with `queue.get`, without any risk of them interfering with each other or the main thread. I demonstrate this in the new edit to my answer.

Comment: It is amazingly clear info my friend! Thanks for sharing! I appreciate your time and efforts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to use an actual thread pool object instead of creating a list of threads yourself, you can use [`QThreadPool`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthreadpool.html):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import Queue as queue
import time

class Signal(QtCore.QObject):
    sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

class Worker(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, theQueue, sig):
        QtCore.QRunnable.__init__(self)
        self.theQueue = theQueue
        self.signal = sig

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task = self.theQueue.get()
            if task is None:
                self.theQueue.task_done()
                return
            time.sleep(1)
            print(task)
            self.signal.sig.emit(int(task))
            self.theQueue.task_done()

def result_callback(result):
    print("Got {}".format(result))

MAX_THREADS = 2
def launch_threads():
    theQueue = queue.Queue()
    pool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
    pool.setMaxThreadCount(MAX_THREADS)
    for task in range(MAX_THREADS): 
        sig = Signal()
        sig.sig.connect(result_callback)
        pool.start(Worker(theQueue, sig))

    for i in range(MAX_THREADS * 6): # Sending more values than there are threads
        theQueue.put(i)

    # Tell the threads in the pool to finish
    for i in range(MAX_THREADS):
        theQueue.put(None)

    pool.waitForDone()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, QtGui.QApplication.instance().exit)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, launch_threads)
    app.exec_()
```

Output:

```
0
 1
2
3
4
5
6
 7
8
 9
10
 11
Got 0
Got 1
Got 2
Got 3
Got 4
Got 5
Got 6
Got 7
Got 8
Got 9
Got 10
Got 11
```

Comment: Is there a way to make `QRunnable` emit the signals?

Comment: @Sputnix I've updated my answer to demonstrate how you could send a signal from the worker in the QThreadPool.

Comment: Thanks Dano! Terrific job! Everything is very clear and straightforward now.